# WPF - TextBox : trigger on text value is not working

Tags: wpf, triggers, textbox, styles

My textbox :

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="50">
            <TextBox.Style>        
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Must be seperated with coma"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused"  Value="True"> 
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>           
        </TextBox>
```

The problem is : when I put my mouse on the textbox, the foreground change in red, that's cool but the text doesn't clear up. Have you any idea of why ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What do you mean by `the text doesn't clear up` ? Why don't you just do `Value=""` ?

Comment: For me works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, it"s working now !! For some reason I have to shut down my Visual and now my style is applied.